# string is not getting printed and showing error of division by zero

Tags: php

string `$unencodedData;` is not getting printed and showing error of division by zero

```
       $date = date_create();
        $timestamp= date_timestamp_get($date);

        $rand = mt_rand(100000,999999);

        $string = "cp-string";


         $unencodedData = "cp-string"/'.$timestamp.'/'.$rand.';

        echo $unencodedData;



           file_put_contents('./public/image/share/image.png',file_get_contents('$unencodedData'));
```

dont know where code is wrong.. hinking may be wrong in declaring $unencodedData;

Comment: You are dividing the strings... what do you think `/` means?

Comment: its for giving different name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It a simple case of miss-matched quote pairs what I think you wanted is :

`$unencodedData = 'cp-string/'.$timestamp.'/'.$rand;`

Also please note that if you don't care about a little overhead you can also use the following to make your code a little more readable :

`$unencodedData = "cp-string/$timestamp/$rand"`;

Answer (score 1):

You may try to declare `$unencodeData` like so

`$unencodeData = 'cp-string/'.$timestamp.'/'.$rand;`

Or if you are trying to use the `$string` var it would be

`$unencodeData = $string.'/'.$timestamp.'/'.$rand;`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to divide strings.. is unencodedData supposed to be a file? If so, try:

```
$unencodedData = $string . '/' . $timestamp . '/' . $rand";
```

or

```
$unencodedData = "{$string}/{$timestamp}/{$rand}";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between `"..."` and `'...'`.

`'...'` means just a basic string, some text. There can't be something special about it. No variables, no linebreak-signs (`\n`),etc.

`"..."` means php has to have a close look at it. Inside `".."` there might be variables like `"My name is $name."` which php replaces with the content of said variable.

If you use `"` inside a `'` or vice versa, it becomes an ordinary string.
You can do something like `"I don't know"`.

If you use `"` inside `"..."` you have to escape it. like so `"and then he said \"I don't know $name\""`. Same goes for `'...'`.

**So what you can do is either:**

`$unencodedData = "cp-string/$timestamp/$rand.";`

or

`$unencodedData = 'cp-string/'.$timestamp.'/'.$rand.'.';`

(just for educational purposes: you could even do something like: 
`$unencodedData = 'cp-string/'.$timestamp."/$rand.";`)

If you don't need to parse any variables or `\n` inside your string, just stick to `''`. It's a little faster parseable for the php interpreter.

Not a 100% sure what your goal is here, but this looks like what I think you are trying to achieve:

```
// -- setup ----------------
$path = './public/image/share/image.png';
$randMin = 100000;
$randMax = 999999

// -- build that string ----
$timestamp= date_timestamp_get(date_create());
$rand = mt_rand($randMin,$randMax);
$unencodedData = "cp-string/$timestamp/$rand.";
// prints something like:   cp-string/19245436/123456.

// -- print and save --------
echo $unencodedData;
file_put_contents($path,file_get_contents($unencodedData));
```